# Getting a 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string' error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have this code:

```
String strDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
DateTime startDateDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate) ? DateTime.Today.AddYears(-10) : DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, strDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime endDateDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.ParseExact(endDate, strDateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string queryStringBlog = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BlogSubcriptionSql] " +
    "where Email like '%_@__%.__%' " +
    "and Email not like '%|%' " +
    "and CreationDate >=  '@startDateDate' " +
    "and CreationDate <=  '@endDateDate' " +
    "order by LastUpdate desc";
```

I am adding the paramaters like this:

```
commandBlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDateDate", startDateDate);
commandBlog.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDateDate", endDateDate);
```

When I eexecute the command and try to read the reader, I get the:

[image]

I tried using SQL convert:

```
string queryStringBlog = "select * from [dbo].[blogsubcriptionsql] " +
    "where email like '%_@__%.__%' " +
    "and email not like '%|%' " +
    "and creationdate >= convert(datetime, '@startDateDate' ) " +
    "and creationdate <= convert(datetime, '@endDateDate' ) " +
    "order by lastupdate desc";
```

But that doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: What type is CreationDate in the database? I hope it is a DateTime type.

Comment: If its a datetime type you should remove the ticks around the parameter in the sql code.

Comment: @Ralf: They need to do that regardless of the type.

Comment: Variables don't get replaced within the SQL query. `'@startDateDate'` is the actual string "@startDateDate", which is not a date/time value.  You wouldn't put variable names in quotes in SSMS, so don't do it in your code. You did try your query in SSMS, right?

Comment: @Ralf CreationDate is of type datetime in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from the string:

```
string queryStringBlog = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BlogSubcriptionSql] " +
        "where Email like '%_@__%.__%' " +
        "and Email not like '%|%' " +
        "and CreationDate >= @startDateDate " +
        "and CreationDate <= @endDateDate " +
        "order by LastUpdate desc";
```